# Alternative injection from $(0,1)$ to $p(\mathbb{N} )$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I know the standard injection is to consider the binary expansion of a number in the interval, but I was wondering if it is possible to create an injection using a decimal expansion.

To that effect first denote the decimal expansion of a $r\in (0,1)$ as $r=0.d_1d_2d_3d_4\dots$.  Choose the decimal expansion of all $x\in (0,1)$ as above except that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \exists m>n$ such that $d_m\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. (This does not exclude any element in the interval).

Now consider the function $f:(0,1)\to p(\mathbb{N})$ where $f(x)=\{2^{d_1},3^{d_2},5^{d_3},\dots,p_i^{d_i},\dots\}$. I believe that Euclid's theorem and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic ensure that $f$ is an injection, but I would like some confirmation.

Comment: (MInor typo: you want $p_i^{d_i}$ in the expression for $f(x)$.) This almost works, but you need to increase the exponents by $1$ so as not to get a bunch of $1$s in $f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry: I slipped up with the first comment, so please check the revised version!

Comment: Damnit I had actually considered that last night while falling asleep but completely forgot to put it in now (not just trying to save face I promise :) )

Comment: `:-)` I know the feeling!

Comment: Oh well my lapse is your gain of at least $10/357000$ reputation points. Thanks for the help. I'll accept your answer when the time restriction ends.

Comment: I didn't know there was a "standard" injection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb N).$ Why isn't it something simpler like $x\mapsto\{2^m(2n+1):\frac mn\lt x\}$?

Comment: @bof the binary representation method is the one I see used most often. Your method could conceivably work, but I don't think it's obvious enough that further proof of injection would not be required. I'm no expert though so perhaps someone else can give a better answer.

Comment: @K.Power It really is an injection; there really is a rational number between any two real numbers. But I suppose this is more advanced than binary representation.

Comment: @bof I'm not doubting the fact that the rationals are dense in the reals, it's just the fact that for each $x$ there are an infinite numbers of $m,n$ that would make me have to look deeper to convince myself it's an injection. I'm not doubting that it is just that like you say it's a more advanced method.

Comment: @K.Power Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R,$ the map $x\mapsto\{q\in\mathbb Q:q\lt x\}$ is an injection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb Q),$ right? So all one has to do is follow this with an injection $\mathcal P(\mathbb Q)\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost works, but if you have more than one $0$ digit, you’ll get multiple copies of $1$ in the description of $f(x)$. To avoid this problem, define

$$f(x)=\left\{p_i^{d_i+1}:i\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;.$$

**Added:** As **Henning Makholm** notes below in the comments, the original idea of setting

$$f(x)=\left\{p_i^{d_i}:i\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$$

actually does work; it just isn’t quite as elegant. If no multiple of some prime $p_i$ appears in $f(x)$, then $d_i=0$, so the $i$-th digit is still reconstructible. In that case the $1\in f(x)$ doesn’t actually tell us anything that we can’t already learn from $f(x)\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: Is that actually a problem? The digit positions whose prime doesn't appear with positive power must be `0`, so we can still reconstruct the original decimal fraction from the set, and the original mapping is in fact injective.

Comment: @Henning: You’re right; it’s just slightly less slick.

Comment: I was just about to comment asking for an example of why my original method wouldn't work. Your edit explains why I couldn't think of one. Thanks again.

Comment: @K.Power: You're welcome. Sorry for the confusion; not one of my better efforts, but at least we got it sorted eventually!